# Clustering of text from social media

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I have been checking out schemes of document clustering like [clustering using k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html) and also [hierarchical clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering). The use case for which I am trying to create clusters is from the social media data which is infinite and would flow in continuously.

I need to create automatic clusters based on the social media data. When a new post comes in and belongs to one of the clusters, it should get attached to the cluster and if there does not exist a cluster in which the new post could be accommodated, it should itself create a new cluster. How could I approach this? What is the clustering that should cover the use case I am trying to work on? Are there any tutorials/examples available for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need an online stream clusterer.

These exist but I don't think they work well.